# HEREMAPS Flutter SDK Navigate Edition - Import Route from Intermodal Routing API

Tags: here-api, heremaps, here-maps-rest, heremap-navigation

Is there an convenient way to import a Route from the [HERE Intermodal Routing API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/intermodal-routing/dev_guide/index.html), like the intendet way to [import Routes from other HERE api](https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.12.5.0/dev_guide/topics/routing.html#import-routes-from-other-services) via a Routehandle? Or an easy other way that doesn't change the Route like importing via GeoCoordinates ?

Comment: Importing via GeoCoordinates does not change the route. In fact, it is only possible to not change the route shape if you add all coordinates from the original route. These are not waypoints, but the points that shape the curvature of the route..

Answer (score 0):

We are supporting  import feature for the routing V8 only. The Route Import service is a REST API that accepts GPS trace points and sub-set of routing parameters. The resulting response will contain a list of routes, which can then be used to consume additional map attributes on the driven path and other parameters such as ETA, traffic incidents, etc.

Sample request.

curl -X GET 
'https://router.hereapi.com/v8/import?apikey={YOUR_API_KEY}&return=polyline,summary,actions,instructions,routeHandle&transportMode=car'
{
"trace": [
{
"lat": 52.541121,
"lng": 13.278989
},
{
"lat": 52.541338,
"lng": 13.276435
},
{
"lat": 52.544976,
"lng": 13.276273
},
{
"lat": 52.546982,
"lng": 13.275723
},
{
"lat": 52.548535,
"lng": 13.276305
},
{
"lat": 52.548535,
"lng": 13.27873
}
]
}

For more details please refer below link.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/route-import.html

Comment: but i need to use intermodal routing  api, not routing.